# Sort values from multiple column and create a new variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
  CityFrom         CityTo   Count
     Paris           Lyon       2
      Lyon          Paris       4
    London     Manchester       5
Manchester         London       6
```

I want to add 2 additional columns to each row that will provide me a city name sorted regardless of the point of destination and origin:

[image]

So, as an example, Lyon-Paris and Paris-Lyon are the same in this case.

My initial idea was:

1. combine the 2 columns i.e. CityFrom and CityTo using `paste`
2. `sort` them alphabetically
3. `split` them in 2 columns.

As a use case, the row with Paris as CityFrom and Lyon as CityTo:

1. `paste` the 2 columns to give - "Paris, Lyon".
2. `sort` to give the output - "Lyon, Paris"
3. `split` into 2 columns with Lyon as CityCodeBidirectionalFrom and Paris as CityCodeBidirectionalto.

I haven't been able to implement the above logic.

Comment: I do not think you can sort by two columns at the same priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need to 'sort', just compare each pair. And you need to do it twice, flipping the condition to get the other from the pair:

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>% 
  mutate(
    CityCodeBidirectionalFrom = if_else(CityFrom < CityTo, CityFrom, CityTo),
    CityCodeBidirectionalTo = if_else(CityFrom > CityTo, CityFrom, CityTo))
```

(as you did not provide any testing data, my code is rather an untested pseudocode than a copy-paste solution...)

Answer (score 1):

For a [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) solution, we can put them into a list, sort them, and then unnest them. Look below;

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)


df1 %>% 
  mutate(CityCodeBidirectional = map2(CityFrom, CityTo, ~sort(c(.x , .y)))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(data = ., col = CityCodeBidirectional, 
                         names_sep = c("From", "To"), names_repair = "universal")

#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   CityFrom   CityTo     Count CityCodeBidirectionalF~ CityCodeBidirectiona~
#>   <chr>      <chr>      <int> <chr>                   <chr>                
#> 1 Paris      Lyon           2 Lyon                    Paris                
#> 2 Lyon       Paris          4 Lyon                    Paris                
#> 3 London     Manchester     5 London                  Manchester           
#> 4 Manchester London         6 London                  Manchester
```

***Data:***

```r
df1 <- read.table(text="CityFrom    CityTo  Count
                        Paris   Lyon    2
                        Lyon    Paris   4
                        London  Manchester  5
                        Manchester London       6",
                  header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: If you are using `map2` you don't need `rowwise`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `pmin()` and `pmax()`.

```
cbind(df, sapply(c(CityCodeBidirectionalFrom = pmin,
                   CityCodeBidirectionalTo = pmax), do.call, df[1:2]))

    CityFrom     CityTo Count CityCodeBidirectionalFrom CityCodeBidirectionalTo
1      Paris       Lyon     2                      Lyon                   Paris
2       Lyon      Paris     4                      Lyon                   Paris
3     London Manchester     5                    London              Manchester
4 Manchester     London     6                    London              Manchester
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the values without the need for concatenation, like this:

```
df = data.frame(
    CityFrom = c("Paris", "Lyon", "London", "Manchester"),
    CityTo = c("Lyon", "Paris", "Manchester", "London"),
    Count = c(2, 4, 5, 6),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

mysort = apply(df[,1:2], 1, sort)
rownames(mysort) = c("CityCodeBidirectionalFrom", "CityCodeBidirectionalTo")
cbind(df, t(mysort), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
##     CityFrom     CityTo Count CityCodeBidirectionalFrom CityCodeBidirectionalTo
## 1      Paris       Lyon     2                      Lyon                   Paris
## 2       Lyon      Paris     4                      Lyon                   Paris
## 3     London Manchester     5                    London              Manchester
## 4 Manchester     London     6                    London              Manchester
```

Comment: I would expect quite longer run times for big data frames (say 10k+ rows), compared to the vectorized tidyverse approach.

Comment: if you are doing apply, then you should just do `df[c("CityCodeBidirectionalFrom", "CityCodeBidirectionalTo")] = t(apply(df[1:2],1,sort))` instead of `mysort` with `rownames` and `cbind`

Comment: I really like this approach. However, this takes really long. As @liborm points out.

Comment: Yes, the solution of H1 using pnim and pmax is better.